# Error in lumen 8.2 - "Class '\App\User' not found"

Tags: laravel, lumen, jwt

I am using JWT with Lumen 8.2.
On login api, when I am entering email and password through postman Its showing and error.

```
Class '\App\User' not found
```

How to solve this error.

in auth.php I am using

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

User.php is in Models folders. Should I need to change something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your information, i think you need to change your model path

```
'model'  => App\Models\User::class,
```

Answer (score 1):

**use App\Models\User**

try this
it will work